# Deep sleep hangs when used with gpio 16 when we connect to reset pin

Tags: arduino-ide, nodemcu, sleep

I have a node MCU and it hangs when I used a deep sleep, as shown in the image attached. My code looks like this:

```cpp
/*
 * ESP8266 Deep sleep mode example
 * Rui Santos 
 * Complete Project Details https://randomnerdtutorials.com
 */
 
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.setTimeout(2000);

  // Wait for serial to initialize.
  while(!Serial) { }
  
  // Deep sleep mode for 30 seconds, the ESP8266 wakes up by itself when GPIO 16 (D0 in NodeMCU board) is connected to the RESET pin
  Serial.println("I'm awake, but I'm going into deep sleep mode for 30 seconds");
  ESP.deepSleep(30e6); 
  
  // Deep sleep mode until RESET pin is connected to a LOW signal (for example pushbutton or magnetic reed switch)
  //Serial.println("I'm awake, but I'm going into deep sleep mode until RESET pin is connected to a LOW signal");
  //ESP.deepSleep(0); 
}

void loop() {
}
```

[image: deepsleep]

Please help!

Comment: remove `while (!Serial)` it doesn't do anything here. add delay(500); after Serial.begin. add Serial.flush before sleep

Comment: tried the same. No changes. Its still the same.

Comment: and what baud rate do you have set in Serial Monitor? do you see the ""I'm awake, but ..." message at first start after upload or at normal reset or power up?

Comment: The serial monitor also had the same baud rate as the code and I don't see that message printed through serial.print command

Comment: did you do all 3 changes I recommended? could you add the modified sketch as edit to the question

Comment: The most important change to implement is the addition of `Serial.flush()` immediately before sleeping - this allows the serial data time to be transmitted before the MCU goes to sleep.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, and I realized I didn't connect GPIO 16 (or D1) to the RST. Sounds trivial, but happens to me.

Old topic I know, but I tried to figure out my mistake and came across this topic, so this might be helpful to some people.

Comment: but the title of the question already has "when used with gpio 16 when we connect to reset pin"